# Pip: When installing pip: "No matching distribution found for install" SSL Error

Tags: openssl, pip

- Pip version: not installed
- Python version: 2.7.0
- Operating system: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

#### Description:

I am trying to install pip on Python 2.7.0. It has to be in this version because I want to use [3Blue1Brown's manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim). However, I get this message when I try to install pip:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for install`

#### What I've run:

When I typed python get-pip.py, I got this message

````
```
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SS
L routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/ins
tall/
c:\users\snake\appdata\local\temp\tmpbgk_ty\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl
_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. Th
is prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL
 connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this
. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-us
age.html#ssl-warnings
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/install/: There was a problem conf
irming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
retries exceeded with url: /simple/install/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ss
l.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol
 version'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for install
```
````

I downloaded OpenSSL from [this website](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and when I type 
`openssl version` in cmd I get this:

> `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`

I *think* OpenSSL is installed correctly, but Python isn't using it (assuming it should).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Python was already running with OpenSSL by doing

```
import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
```

The version was very old. And, if possible, a user told me it would be very complicated to update its OpenSSL. Therefore, what I did was simply downloading Python 2.7.15 and it solved.